# Unity 5 unresponsive after a piece of code is executed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a absolute beginner in unity. I have been working on an UI which is a simple login form. In which I have two `Toggle` for selecting gender i.e male or female. What I have been doing is that calling a method which checks if a male is already selected it will remove the check from male when the other toggle is pressed.

My `Unity` freezes when I click the female `Toogle`. here is my code.

```
Toggle female;
Toggle male;
void Start(){
    female = GameObject.Find ("toggle_female").GetComponent<Toggle> ();
     male = GameObject.Find ("toggle_male").GetComponent<Toggle> ();
}

 public void isMale(){
    if (female.isOn)
        female.isOn = false;

    male.isOn = true;

}

public void isFemale(){
    if (male.isOn)
        male.isOn = false;

    female.isOn = true;
}
```

Comment: You want a toggle that only male or female can be selected but not both?

Comment: yes. thats what i am trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running into infinite loop with your [`Toggle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Toggle.html).

When the female toggle changes, the [`onValueChanged`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Toggle-onValueChanged.html) event is triggered. I assume that your `isFemale()` function is linked with the Toggle [`onValueChanged`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Toggle-onValueChanged.html) event, so `isFemale()` will be called.

When `isFemale()` is called, it will do `male.isOn = false;` causing 
`isMale()` function to be called which will then run `female.isOn = false;` causing `isFemale()` to be called again. This is everlasting.

The [`onValueChanged`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Toggle-onValueChanged.html) event should never be fired when `isOn` is set from script. This is the problem.

**Solution**:

You are looking for the [ToggleGroup](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.ToggleGroup.html).

**1**.Create male toggle **GameObject** *->* **UI** *->* **Toggle** then name it *Male toggle*.

**2**.Create female toggle **GameObject** *->* **UI** *->* **Toggle** then name it *Female toggle*. You can change the label text later on.

**3**.Create an empty GameObject. **GameObject** *->* **Create Empty**.
Rename it to *ToggleGroup*.

Select the newly created GameObject, go to **Component** *->* **ToggleGroup**. Now, you have GameObject called *ToggleGroup* with `ToggleGroup` Component attached to it.

**4**.Select your *Male toggle*, then drag the *ToggleGroup* GameObject into *Male toggle's* `Group` slot. Select your *Female toggle*, then drag the *ToggleGroup* GameObject into *Female toggle's* `Group` slot

Select your *Female toggle*, then *unckeck* **Is On** checkbox to make sure that only one(*Male toggle*) is selected by default. Click play and now, only one toggle can be selected at a time.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. i did know about `ToggleGroup` but had no idea how to use it. thnx for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the two functions isMale and isFemale are Toggles' event handlers. According to Unity docs:

> The Toggle has a single event called On Value Changed that responds
>   when the user changes the current value

So the problem is that these event handlers respond to value change and not toggle being checked, so your code causes an infinite loop. It should work by reading them first to make sure it's a check and not uncheck:

```
 public void isMale(){
    if (!male.isOn) return;

    if (female.isOn)
        female.isOn = false;

    male.isOn = true;

}

public void isFemale(){
    if (!female.isOn) return;

    if (male.isOn)
        male.isOn = false;

    female.isOn = true;
}
```